# NHibernate Criteria select items by the group by and sum of itemid within another table

Tags: nhibernate, criteria, aggregate, nhibernate-projections

```
public class SearchText
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
}

public class SearchTextLog
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual SearchText SearchText { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual int SearchCount { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime LastSearchDate { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to select the top 5 SearchText items based on the sum of their count within the SearchTextLog.   Currently I have only been able to resolve this by first performing a query to get the top 5 items, and then using the result within a second query.  I was wondering if someone could show me the light and teach me how I could integrate these two seperate queries into a single unit.

Here is what I have currently:

```
var topSearchCriteria = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof (SearchTextLog))
            .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
                            .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("SearchText.Id"))
                            .Add(Projections.Alias(Projections.Sum("SearchCount"), "SearchCount")))
            .AddOrder(Order.Desc("SearchCount"))
            .SetMaxResults(topSearchLimit)
            .List<int>();

return Session.CreateCriteria<SearchText>()
            .Add(Restrictions.In("Id", topSearchCriteria.ToArray()))
            .List<SearchText>();
```

**Edit:**

Oh no, I just realised my current solution will lose the important order by of the results.  So I will definitely have to incorporate the queries.  :-/

**Edit:**

I tried a bidirectional mapping too to allow the following statement, however, I can't get it to return SearchText items.  It simply complains that the SearchText properties aren't in a grouping.

```
return Session.CreateCriteria<SearchText>()
                .CreateAlias("SearchTextLogs", "stl")
                .AddOrder(Order.Desc(Projections.Sum("stl.SearchCount")))
                .SetMaxResults(topSearchLimit)        
                .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToEntityMap)
                .List<SearchText>();
```

Excuse my ignorance, but Nhibernate is completely new to me, and requires a completely different way of thinking.

Comment: check the updated code, i think you need both GroupProperty (to generate group by) as wellas Projections.Property to tell the query engine to generate that property in the select

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, I think I have figured out a solution.

My original solution as per my question won't work because NHibernate doesn't yet support the ability to do a group by property without adding it to the select clause (see: [link text](http://216.121.112.228/browse/NH-1426)).

While fooling around however, I came across these cool things called ResultTransformers.  Using the AliasToBean result transformer Nhibernate will automatically map the alias's I give to each projection item to properties by the same name within a type I specify.  I simply specified my SearchText object (however, I had to add an additional TotalSearchCount property for the sum projection item).  It populated my objects perfectly and returned them.

```
return Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(SearchTextLog))
            .CreateAlias("SearchText", "st")
            .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
                                .Add(Projections.Alias(Projections.GroupProperty("st.Id"), "Id"))
                                .Add(Projections.Alias(Projections.GroupProperty("st.Text"), "Text"))
                                .Add(Projections.Alias(Projections.Sum("SearchCount"), "TotalSearchCount")))
            .SetMaxResults(topSearchLimit)
            .AddOrder(Order.Desc("TotalSearchCount"))
            .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(SearchText)))
            .List<SearchText>();
```

I am surprised this wasn't easier to do.  It's taken me about 4 to 5 hours of research and dev to figure this one out.  Hopefully my NHibernate experience will get easier with more and more experience.

I hope this helps someone else out there!

Answer (score 1):

doesn't this work?

```
var critterRes = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof (SearchTextLog))
            .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
                            .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("SearchText"))
                            .Add(Projections.Property("SearchText"))
                            .Add(Projections.Alias(Projections.Sum("SearchCount"), "SearchCount")))
            .AddOrder(Order.Desc("SearchCount"))
            .SetMaxResults(topSearchLimit)
            .List<SearchText>()
```

Comment: I did try something like that already.  I get the following exception though: 
The value "System.Object[]" is not of type "SearchText" and cannot be used in this generic collection.

Comment: This *should* work if you call `List<Object[]>()`.  You do not get a list of typed objects, but if you can deal with an `IList<Object[]>` you will not have to create a value holder class for your results.  It is probably not as clean as the accepted solution though.