# NHibernate criteria to count unique visits

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have two tables, for this example I'll them Vists and Cities.

Visits

- UserAccountID (Mapped to the UserAccount property)
- CityID (Mapped to the City property)
- VisitDate

Cities

- CityID
- Name

I want to write a criteria which will return the number of different cities a particular user has visited.

So far I have:

```
       return this.Framework.GetSession().CreateCriteria<Visits>()
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("UserAccount", user))
            .SetProjection(Projections.Count(Projections.Id()))
            .UniqueResult<int>();
```

However when I have a user who has visited:

- London
- Manchester
- Leeds
- London

This query will return 4, I'm after the number of different cities visited (in this case 3).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `Projections.GroupProperty("CityID")` [(official documentation)](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria-projection) ? It should be able to achieve your desired results.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290076/nhibernate-criteria-select-items-by-the-group-by-and-sum-of-itemid-within-anothe) might also prove helpful.